# Nextflow: transforming input of fromFilePairs into a tuple of (map, list_pair_1, list_pair_2)

Tags: groovy, nextflow

In my Nextflow workflow, I need to process files similar to the below example.

```
a.vcf.gz
a.vcf.gz.tbi
b.vcf.gz
b.vcf.gz.tbi
c.vcf.gz
c.vcf.gz.tbi
```

In particular, I need to create a channel which will output them with this structure:

```
[
    ["id": "test"], 
    ["a.vcf.gz", "b.vcf.gz", "c.vcf.gz"], 
    ["a.vcf.gz.tbi", "b.vcf.gz.tbi", "c.vcf.gz.tbi"]
]
```

This means a tuple of a single map, one tuple of `*.vcf.gz` files and one tuple of `*.vcf.gz.tbi` files.

My problem is that, from my reading of the documentation, it's not evident how to create it from a channel that emits items sequentially in groups of three.

For simplicity, I collect the files from pairs using `Channel.fromFilePairs`:

```
ch_input = Channel
    .fromFilePairs("*{.vcf.gz,.vcf.gz.tbi}")
```

This is where I got stuck. The closest I've got was by scrapping `fromFilePairs` and using `groupTuple`:

```
 ch_input = Channel
    .fromPath("*.vcf.gz*")
    .map {
       file ->
       def fmeta = ["id": "test"]
       value = file.extension == "gz" ? "vcf": "tbi"
       [value, file]
     }.groupTuple()
    
    println ch_input.view()
```

Which gives:

```
[tbi, [/Users/einar/Coding/a.vcf.gz.tbi, /Users/einar/Coding/c.vcf.gz.tbi, /Users/einar/Coding/einar/b.vcf.gz.tbi]]
[vcf, [/Users/einar/Coding/b.vcf.gz, /Users/einar/Coding/a.vcf.gz, /Users/einar/Coding/c.vcf.gz]]
```

Which still is far away from what I'd like and more fragile because it relies on file extensions.

`Channel.multiMap` is close to what I want, however it generates multiple channels, while instead I need a single channel.

How can this be done properly?

**EDIT**:

This is another attempt, which gets what I want, however it looks kind of hacky and fragile to me:

```
ch_input = Channel
        .fromPath("*.vcf*")
        .map{
            file -> 
            [file.extension, file]
        }.groupTuple()
        .map {
         it ->
          def fmeta = ["id": "test"]
          [fmeta, it[1].flatten()]
         }.groupTuple()
         .map{
           it -> 
           [it[0], it[1][0], it[1][1]]
         }

    
    println ch_input.view()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want, you'd need the [collect](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collect) operator which gives you a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel):

```
Channel
    .fromFilePairs( '/path/to/files/*.vcf.gz{,.tbi}' )
    .collect { sample, indexed_vcf -> [ indexed_vcf ] }
    .map { 
        def fmeta = [ "id": "test" ]

        [ fmeta, it*.first(), it*.last() ] 
    } 
    .view()
```

It's difficult to say without the details, but usually you don't need to separate out the index files from the actual VCF files. If this channel is to be used directly as process input, my preference would be to alter the input declaration so that I could use something like this instead:

```
Channel
    .fromPath( '/path/to/files/*.vcf.gz{,.tbi}' )
    .collect()
    .map { 
        def fmeta = ["id": "test"]

        [ fmeta, it ]
    } 
    .view()
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'll test next Monday when I'm in the office and report back.

Comment: As for the motivation (I forgot to write it when I replied): the process I'm using (not written by me) takes `tuple meta, path(vcf), path(tbi)` as inputs, where `vcf` is a list of VCF files, and `tbi` the same, for indices (not used directly, just to copy them into the staging area).